# EF4 And POCO Class and Inheritance and Error Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType

Tags: c#, mapping, poco

I have a POCO Class with name TaskWeek in my business layer and in my presentation layer I defined a new Class:

```
public class TaskWeekUI : TaskWeek
{
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public string PersianEndDate
    {
        get
        {
            return UIUtility.ConvertToPersianDate(EndDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a method  public void Save(List taskweeks) , When I want to call this method I convert a List and call this method:

```
            using (TaskWeekDA twa = new TaskWeekDA())
            {
                IEnumerable<TaskWeek> tw = MainObjects.twUi.OfType<TaskWeek>();
                twa.Save(tw.ToList());
            }
```

but instead to save I've got this error :
Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inheriting from TaskWeek is it possible for you to write your methods in a partial class?

For example, write a TaskWeek.part.cs like:

```
//namespace has to be the same as TaskWeek that your model generated
public partial class TaskWeek
{
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public string PersianEndDate
    {
        get
        {
            return UIUtility.ConvertToPersianDate(EndDate);
        }
    }
}
```

This way the EF has info about the class type, and you have the same functionality as with inheriting (that is, if you're not using inheritance for some other stuff).

Comment: If I need to be in seperate Namespace , does it have a solution?

Comment: If it needs to be in a separate namespace, than it probably deserves a class of it's own - then you could create an instance of that class in your partial class like above, but as far as I know, partial classes cannot span different namespaces...